# How to implement Charts in SwiftUI?

Tags: charts, swiftui

How can I make a *chart view* using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library in SwiftUI

In other words, how to make a `UIViewRepresentable` for it?

Comment: Please, be at least a bit more specific. What have you tried? Can you show us some code to reproduce the issue you are facing?

Comment: @dfd Lets say I want to create a *chart view* that looks like one of the examples of the library (say `PieChart`s). 2 questions: **1-** which way is better: Using *pods* or *Swift Packages* **2-** How to create `UIViewRepresentable` for that example chart

Comment: Let's say you wish to do [fill in the library here] in SwiftUI. What is SwiftUI? A way of managing your views. Pods, Swift Packages, copy/paste - it doesn't matter - is Swift, not SwiftUI. Can you do this in UIKit? If so, **then** you have something you can do in SwiftUI as a `UIViewRepresentable`. But first, get it working in `UIKit`. Try then to get it into either a `UIViewRepresentable` or a `UIViewControllableRepresentable`. I'm not trying to sound harsh, but instead I'm trying to point you in a direction. Continued...

Comment: Okay, let's say you can do that (to me) SwiftUI basics. Create a `UIView` or `UIViewController`. Make it "representable". Are you now having an issue with your model? (Trust me, this was a paradigm shift for me.) If so, show some code, hopefully enough for anyone to reproduce things. Tying together your model (is it an `ObservableObject`?) with your `UIKit` library (does it have delegates? do you need to create a coordinator?) is probably the toughest challenge. But first? If it's a `UIViewRepresentable`, get it working in a `UIKit` project first.

Comment: @dfd I was watching a tutorial on [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/) by [Brian Advent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNf-SsDBQ20) and I was wondering if I could make this kind of view using SwiftUI elements.

Comment: Pure SwiftUI? I'm guessing not (at least yet). Here's the best I know of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100110/in-swiftui-how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-rectangle-for-a-bar-chart but since it's a bar chart and not a pie chart, maybe this can help you? https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E164-paths-and-shapes I'd probably go the `UIKit` route with a representable - if possible.

Comment: @dfd Not pure *SwiftUI*, I meant using `Text` and `Steppers` (and maybe Bindings ) of SwiftUI + a view for representing the ChartView (which conforms to the `UIViewRepresentable` protocol)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is some sample code that should get you started. Not sure if this is best practice, but it was the easiest way to get me going with Charts and SwiftUI. Hope this helps!

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct GraphSwiftUI: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { p in
            VStack {
                LineChartSwiftUI()
                    //use frame to change the graph size within your SwiftUI view
                    .frame(width: p.size.width, height: p.size.height/5, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LineChartSwiftUI: UIViewRepresentable {
    let lineChart = LineChartView()

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LineChartSwiftUI>) -> LineChartView {
        setUpChart()
        return lineChart
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: LineChartView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LineChartSwiftUI>) {

    }

    func setUpChart() {
        lineChart.noDataText = "No Data Available"
        let dataSets = [getLineChartDataSet()]
        let data = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
        data.setValueFont(.systemFont(ofSize: 7, weight: .light))
        lineChart.data = data
    }

    func getChartDataPoints(sessions: [Int], accuracy: [Double]) -> [ChartDataEntry] {
        var dataPoints: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        for count in (0..<sessions.count) {
            dataPoints.append(ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(sessions[count]), y: accuracy[count]))
        }
        return dataPoints
    }

    func getLineChartDataSet() -> LineChartDataSet {
        let dataPoints = getChartDataPoints(sessions: [0,1,2], accuracy: [100.0, 20.0, 30.0])
        let set = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataPoints, label: "DataSet")
        set.lineWidth = 2.5
        set.circleRadius = 4
        set.circleHoleRadius = 2
        let color = ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom()[0]
        set.setColor(color)
        set.setCircleColor(color)
        return set
    }
}

struct GraphSwiftUI_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GraphSwiftUI()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nas5296 So I have this snippet accepting an array of chart data, however I cannot get my chart to update?  The array is implementing @ Published song with a view model that is an @ observed object.  the list gets updated, but the chart does not reload.  any ideas on why the chart is not updating?

Comment: I too have this problem :( Seems to update once and only once, very strange

Comment: Anyone try implementing a Spider (aka Radar) chart/graph yet?

Comment: This seems reasonable but for some reason when I try this it results in a yellow background with a red "crossed out" type symbol on it. Looks like the ghostbuster symbol without a ghost. Not sure if that's SwiftUI or Chart's way of telling me something didn't work. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: @Jackson I wonder if something has changed in the latest update of Xcode/SwiftUI. I haven't played around with the newer versions yet, but my guess is the issue is related to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the view of the graph every time the data changes, add a `UpdateData()` function where you set and return your `LineChartData()` object.

Then set `uiView.data = UpdateData()` and call `uiView.notifyDataSetChanged()`.
This should re-render your graph.